# jquery setting options after init

Tags: jquery-selectors

I know one can set plugin options, after things are set.  But I'm not quite sure how to do it.  So I created a simple jquery UI example, using the draggable(), with zIndex option already set.  So, if I click the link I created, I want to change the zIndex option to another integer. Here's the link I am work from: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-zIndex

```
<script>
$(function() {

  $( ".dragimgs" ).draggable({ zIndex: 2700 });


});
</script>

<img class="dragimgs" src="someimg.png" />

<a id="clickme">Click To Change zIndex</a>
```

So the question is how do I reset the zIndex (or any available option), dynamically.
I am assuming that a js function or some onclick event can be utilized, but I honestly don't know how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `.draggable( "option" , "optionName" , value )` to change your `zIndex`

Putting that together with the zIndex it would look like the following...

```
$("#clickme").click(function() {
    $(".dragimgs").draggable("option", "zIndex", 1000);
});
```

**[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/wkpqS/1/)**

Comment: So, from what I'm understanding, I just need to restate the selector and plugin again?  That was easy.

Comment: @coffeemonitor, just to clarify, this answer calls the setter method. [This is outlined in the docs.](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-zIndex) Any option for draggable can be set using this method.